# How to handle 1000 requests per second in spring boot rest API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am newbie in Spring boot. We are implementing one spring boot microservice application.

As spring boot uses embedded tomcat server, by default thread pool is 200.

So whats the best approach to increase the capactiy to handle 1000 requests?

Do we need to make it async or?

Any inputs are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This highly depends on what your service is doing with a request. Using reactive frameworks might be a solution, but if you e.g. access a database behind, then you have to deal with that, for example.

Comment: You can increase the thread pool of the embedded tomcat by setting ```server.tomcat.threads.max```, but there are a lot of other factors you have to deal with ...

Answer (score 9):

There is hardware capacity (RAM, CPU etc) So you can not set any number of thread in pool (like 1000 in your case). Also it depends on execution time of each request.

To handle high traffic, you should setup **Load Balancer** with multiple node/instances.

Better to go with **Auto Scaling** on Cloud server. It will increase the instances as per high load (number of request) and again decrease the instances when there will be low number of requests. Which is cost effective.

Answer (score 8):

There is no single parameter which would ensure that your application will handle 1000 requests in parallel. 
 It depends on many factors, like:

1. What is the average execution time for your request. e.g. If your request only needs nanoseconds to return then X number of threads could suffice to serve Y parallel requests (even when X<Y).
2. Available resources: Sometimes even if number of threads is *greater than* number of parallel requests (X>Y), it may not be able to process them simultaneously if the resources are limited (e.g. RAM, Processing power, max number of database connections) etc.

So, in real life, it all depends on lot of factors (not covered above) which are taken care by software architecture which in turn takes care of your functional as well as non functional requirements. So, even if your number of requests change from 1000 to 10000, your architecture will take care of it if it is Scalable.

Knowing which parameter to tune may suffice for now, for future though, look at quality attributes in software architecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_system_quality_attributes

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it too easy? It is enough for the application to respond in less than 200ms per request? (Theoretically)
Since we have 200 threads, we can handle 200 requests in parallel. To get 1000rps/200 = 5. So each thread needs to handle 5 requests in a second, i.e. respond <= 200ms

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things that can be considered

1. Checking the instance types application is using and the resources it offers (i.e Compute capacity)
2. Ensure auto scaling kick in the case of spike in traffic.
3. Consider using min_idle_instances for your services which can readily start serving traffic without any warm up time.